# Trouble comparing value in C

Tags: c

I am having problem comparing an int value and a char value in C. Lets say I variable int value1 that is 0 and a char that has value '0'. I know that that char's value is actually an ascii number and that '0' is 48, but how do I compare int's 0 value with chars '0' value, in an if statement as a example?

Comment: "is actually an ascii number" - not necessarily.

Comment: `if(int_value == char_value - '0')`

Comment: You should also cast the result (int)(char_value - '0') or the compiler will issue warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the idiom `c - '0'` to convert a `char` `c` to its equivalent digit.

This is an expression of type `int`.

Note that it works in any character *encoding* supported by the C Standard, since such an encoding must order 0 to 9 consecutively.